# How to find PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY in Stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

How can i get PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY in my test stripe account
i am payment using stripe connect

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY);
    $tr = \Stripe\Payout::create(array(
      "amount" => 24784,
      "currency" => "usd",
      "source_type" => "bank_account"
    ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This represents the API key of your own account so it can be found in your dashboard: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys

You would be acting as the platform where you make API requests on behalf of your connected accounts which is why you would use your own API key. You **also** need to pass the connected account id in the `Stripe-Account` header as documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#authentication-via-the-stripe-account-header). The code should look like this:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY);
$payout = \Stripe\Payout::create(
  array(
    "amount" => 24784,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "source_type" => "bank_account"
  ),
  array(
    "stripe_account" => "acct_XXXXX"
  )
));
```

Comment: `$payout = \Stripe\Payout::create(
  array(
    "amount" => 24784,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "source_type" => "bank_account"
  ),
  array(
    "stripe_account" => "acct_1BboLxFtYsB7beiB"
  )
);
    print_r($payout);`

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help with "not working", I need a lot more details. This is not really a stackoverflow question in that case and you should contact Stripe's support team: https://support.stripe.com/email